# Loopback ACL on an individual property?

Tags: loopbackjs, acl

It's possible to set ACL on a method basis in Loopback. For instance you can set Access Levels on `Find, Update, Delete` etc. Is there a way to filter out sensitive properties on models?

Say I want to expose my user model via REST, but I want certain properties protected by ACL. For example maybe I don't want to expose `phoneNumber` or `address` if the query isn't made by the owner or an administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I see two different ways you could achieve this:

- Extend the basic User model with your own remote method findById and check for the user roles, exposing different data to them.
- Add a "before" remote hook to findById and check if the user is $owner - if he is call next, if not, call a custom method that returns the data you want to expose to public (check out https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks), not 100% sure this works for built in user methods thought

hope this helps,
greetz